# NameError: name 'air' is not defined

Tags: python, nameerror

I am a python beginner, the situation is:

**In test.py**:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from numpy import * 

def model(file):
    import numpy as np
    import pandas as pd

    data0 = pd.ExcelFile(file)
    data = data0.parse('For Stata')
    data1 = data.values
    varnames = list(data)

    for i in range(np.shape(data)[1]):
        var = varnames[i]
        exec(var+'=np.reshape(data1[:,i],(2217,1))')

    return air
```

air is one of the 'varnames'

---

**Now I run the following in jupyter notebook**:

```
file0 = 'BLPreadydata.xlsx'
from test import model
model(file0)
```

---

the error that I get is:
**NameError: name 'air' is not defined**

EDIT: I tried to pin down the error, it actually came from

```
exec(var+'=np.reshape(data1[:,i],(2217,1))')
```

somehow this is not working when I call the function, but it does work when I run it outside the function.

NOTE: 
Someone have done this in MATLAB:

```
vals = [1 2 3 4]
vars = {'a', 'b', 'c', 'd'}
for i = vals
    eval([vars{i} '=  vals(i)'])
end
```

Comment: The 1st and only mention of `air` is when you return it… What did you expect?

Comment: Why are you using `exec()`? And there is no need to re-import modules in the function, it's just clutter.

Comment: @LtWorf when i=6 then var = 'air', then exec(.) does air = data.

Comment: @roganjosh I am using exec(.) because I wanted to assign the data to variables named var in varnames.

Comment: I don't think exec does what you think it does.

Comment: It does work fine if I run the code separately, but when I put them in a function and call that function the error pops up..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an answer after reading the exec(.) doc and guessing...

air is actually saved as a local variable after exec(.)...

hence, instead of

```
return air
```

put

```
return locals()['air']
```

Thanks for all the help.

Answer (score 0):

You should use one more for loop in function to iterate varnames and find 'air, if found then store it another variable and return that variable.
Try this.

```
for j in varnames:
    if j=='air':
       c=j
```

Then return c.

```
return c
```

Comment: What is `i`? What is the point of the loop anyway when you could just do `c = 'air'`. This answer is more obscure than the question.

Comment: Sorry this is j.

Comment: The assignment of `c = j` is still superfluous. Why don't you just `return j` if the match is found and short circuit the loop? This suggestion is only relevant to the code you've given, I'm still not sure how any of this addresses the question.

Comment: I tried this, it only returns a string 'air', but air should contain data because of exec(.) @kaleem231

Comment: When you write just return air, Python recognize it as a variable therefore i define it as a string

Comment: Hi, that is what I wanted to do, I want to return the variable air which contains a column of data... @kaleem231

Comment: Then you should iterate varnames and extract air from them and then return it.